# Loading an ICC profile on Raspberry Pi doesn't work

Tags: display, xorg

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (non-plus) together with the official 7 inch touchscreen connected to the DSI connector. The latest Raspbian 2018-03-13 is installed. This works fine, but the display has not exactly the most vivid color rendition. I generated a ICC profile for the display with my Spyder 4 colorimeter using Argyll CMS and dispcalgui.

When I try to apply the profile using xcalib, nothing happens. The display output still looks the same.

The question [xcalib not working on Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9247/xcalib-not-working-on-raspberry-pi) seems to be related, but it was resolved in a different way not compatible with my usecase.

**Update:** In the mean time, I also tried the different graphics driver options in raspi-config. With the OpenGL drivers, I get the error message

```
Error - unsupported ramp size 0
```

**Update 2:**
When trying to change brightness with xrandr as proposed by @EricAnholt I get the message

```
xrandr: Gamma size is 0.
```

when using the legacy driver and no message when using the OpenGL driver. Both times, no change in brightness can be observed.

Comment: Does plain xrandr --output <your-output-name> --brightness 2 successfully change the gamma ramps?  If so, then this is possibly an issue in the app you're using instead of the vc4 driver.

Comment: @EricAnholt Thanks for the hint, let me check this tonight. I will update my question accordingly.