# Display colour (ICC) profile on Raspberry Pi 400 running Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: ubuntu

I have a display, which really requires applying proper correction in order to deliver good, readable output. It's never been a problem on x86/amd64 Ubuntu. Now I have it connected to a Pi 400 running Ubuntu 20.10 and my display's profile is completely ignored. I noticed a few [similar](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82891/loading-an-icc-profile-on-raspberry-pi-doesnt-work) [questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9247/xcalib-not-working-on-raspberry-pi), relating to older Pis and different OS. Still they have either no, or no applicable answers. Any hints how to enable ICC profile on the 400?

Comment: I would have thought its application and desktop dependant.  I know the Mac machines have profile support built in to the OS (I used a Spyder on mine) - I've heard of https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-color-manager but not tried it (all my Pi boxes are headless and the Mac is the photo editing box) GIMP has https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-imaging-color-management.html

Comment: @Andrew - there is everything that's needed for that in Ubuntu. And it works all OK. Except on the Pi (400).